# How to achieve actual parallel execution of jobs on Azure Pipelines on pool of Microsoft-hosted agents?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pretty simple but slow (~15 min) Node test that I want to run on Ubuntu and Linux, and for each on Node 6, 8 and 10 - so 6 "jobs" in total - via an Azure Pipeline on Azure DevOps.

My `azure-pipeline.yml` looks like this:

```
jobs:
- job: Ubuntu
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      node_6_x:
        node_version: 6.x
      node_8_x:
        node_version: 8.x
      node_10_x:
        node_version: 10.x
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      version: $(node_version)
    displayName: 'Install Node.js $(node_version)'  
  - script: |
      npm install
    displayName: 'npm install'
  - script: |
      npm run test
    displayName: 'npm test'
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      node_6_x:
        node_version: 6.x
      node_8_x:
        node_version: 8.x
      node_10_x:
        node_version: 10.x
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      version: $(node_version)
    displayName: 'Install Node.js $(node_version)'  
  - script: |
      npm install
    displayName: 'npm install'
  - script: |
      npm test
    displayName: 'npm test'
```

As this is an open source repository on GitHub, I would have expected these 6 test runs to happen in parallel (as there should be 10 parallel jobs possible).

Observing the pipeline runs of the pull request adding the `azure-pipeline.yml` to my repository, it seems like there only sometimes seems to be some parallelism going on. Often I wait minutes for *any* job to start. Is this maybe a capacity problem on Azure Pipelines side, that no agents to run the tests are available?

When something starts, it is mostly just 1 job per operating system, while the others from the `matrix` are "Not started / Queued". Shouldn't `matrix` jobs be executed in parallel?

---

Which brings me to my real question:
Is there a way to achieve actual parallel execution of jobs on Azure Pipelines on the pools of Microsoft-hosted agents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing

```
  strategy:
    matrix:
      node_6_x:
        node_version: 6.x
      node_8_x:
        node_version: 8.x
      node_10_x:
        node_version: 10.x
```

to

```
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 3
    matrix:
      node_6_x:
        node_version: 6.x
      node_8_x:
        node_version: 8.x
      node_10_x:
        node_version: 10.x
```

(note the additional `maxParallel: 3`) seems to have done the job: The builds are now started all together as soon as the commit to the PR branch is made.

While `maxParallel` is currently only documented as ["restricts the amount of parallelism."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#multi-configuration), it seems to be needed to get parallelism for `matrix` configurations at all.

(Documentation for [Job in the YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts#job) doesn't help as it shows `maxParallel` as an alternative to `matrix` or `parallel`.)