# Azure pipeline not run matrix jobs in parallel

Tags: azure, parallel-processing, rust, azure-devops

Despite setting what [How to achieve actual parallel execution of jobs on Azure Pipelines on pool of Microsoft-hosted agents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369252/how-to-achieve-actual-parallel-execution-of-jobs-on-azure-pipelines-on-pool-of-m) recommend, the azure pipelines I have always run sequentially. I was expecting to run in both linux/windows in parallel:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'master'

strategy:
  maxParallel: 2
  matrix:
    windows-stable:
      imageName: 'windows-latest'
      rustup_toolchain: stable
    linux-stable:
      imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      rustup_toolchain: stable

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)

steps:
  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update &&
      sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates &&
      sudo apt install libncursesw5-dev
      wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
      sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
      sudo apt-get update &&
      sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-11 postgresql-contrib-11 postgresql-client-11
      echo "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5" > sudo tee -a /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf &&
      sudo service postgresql restart && sleep 3 &&
      sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE \"BestSeller2\"" &&
      sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'pinkycerebro';" &&
               sudo service postgresql restart && sleep 3
    displayName: Install PG
    condition: ne( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
  - script: |
      choco install llvm
      refreshenv
    displayName: Install CLANG
    condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )

  - script: cargo test --all
    displayName: Cargo test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps has restrictions on the number of paralel jobs you can launch at the same time. It depends on your scenario:

1. Microsoft hosted CI/CD. At the time of this post it is 1 free job (limited to 60 minutes running) for Private projects, and up to 10 for Public project.
2. Self hosted CI/CD. At the time of this answer it is 1 free job + 1 free additional job per Visual Studio Enterprise Subscriber or unlimited jobs for the public projects.

So, I'd recommend you to check first if that could be the reason of not paralelization in 
your pipelines. If you are on a private project without any VS Enterprise Subscription you should consider moving to Public project or to keep at least two Agent Pools (one self-hosted CI/CD other for Microsoft Hosted CI/CD) if you want to get some degree of paralelization.

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops to check the latest documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this clarify the situation.