# Automated Repeated Python Tasks In Azure Pipeline Tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an application that run a pipeline. Every time that pipeline running, there are two repeated task :
[image]

Command line script is:

```html
pip install -r scripts/requirements.txt
```

Is it possible to running these two tasks once? The python script running 30 times a day and the the pipeline installs libraries 30 times.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to run tasks in parallel, you'd need more than one agent. You may also want to use YAML pipelines. 
Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369252/how-to-achieve-actual-parallel-execution-of-jobs-on-azure-pipelines-on-pool-of-m

Comment: If you are using microsoft's hosted agents, then the answer is no; each agent is built fresh, and you need to install the dependencies you need.

Comment: But if you are using self-hosted agents on your own VM, then the answer is yes. You could make sure that the common requirements are already installed on that VM, and wouldn't need those tasks in the pipeline – or you could leave the tasks in but they would run faster.